# How to convert existing executable to web service?

Tags: web-services, executable

We have existing executable programs on the server such as bash, perl and C++ command line applications.
We are running them such as

```
app_name <input_param_1> <input_param_2>
```

Executables give text output after process.

We want to run these applications and get output through web or mobile.

How can we give web service with minimum effort and no modification to executables.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You basically make your text output include http headers--at least, a content-type (and text/plain is a valid content type)--and any desired html markup or formatting. Which is perhaps a executable modification, yes, or you might be wrapping it in a script.

However, I can't speak to the security and performance implications without knowing more about the executables in question. My recommendation would be to hire a web developer to convert the executables to legitimate web applications instead.